# How do i import functions from multiple files that can change in numbers and names in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to make a loop that imports every function in every file in a function and use input to run that function i wanted to put the files individially so i can add more of them

right now i only have 1 file callde quit.py with a function inside also called quit:

```
def quit():
    raise Exception("bye")
```

in main.py i tried doing this

```
import os 

commands=[]
for file in os.listdir(r"funcs"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        commands.append(file)
        file=file[:-3]
        from funcs import file
        

print(commands)
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'file' from 'funcs' (unknown location)

Comment: @Avantgarde the error is not in `os.listdir` but in the `import` statement. `from funcs import file` try to find a `"file.py"` in directory `"funcs"`. So to read `"funcs/file.py"` somewhere in python path. When OP needs to read some `"funcs/quit.py"` in that path, if variable `file` has value `"quit"`.

Comment: It's not a good approach to import all functions inside all files. There might be multiple functions inside different files with the same name and you will override them. You better import each file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not so much useless and not much security, but u can  add the path in the "sys.path", import using "importlib.util" and adding in global variables:

```
from glob import glob
import sys
import pathlib
import importlib.util

sys.path.append(r".\funcs")
for file in glob(r".\funcs\*.py"):
    file = pathlib.Path(file)
    sys.path.append(file)
    imported_module = importlib.import_module(file.stem)
    globals().update(imported_module.__dict__)
```

Answer (score -1):

`file` is a variable here.
But import statement doesn't work with a variable. It takes `file` literally as meaning `"file"`.
You are certainly used to it. I guess you never wrote `import "math"`, `import "numpy"` or `import "sys"`, but `import math` `import numpy` or `import sys`.

So you known that the argument is a quoteless string, not an expression.
Exactly as `funcs` is, btw, in the exact same command: you are expecting `funcs` to be taken literally (meaning the directory with actual name "funcs", not the directory whose name is given by variable funcs), while expecting `file` to be taken as an expression (meaning the python file whose name is found in variable `file`, not the python file with actual name `"file.py"`)

What you could do is call the `__import__` function, that behaves more as you would expect

```py
mymod = __import__('funcs', file)
```

And there, you have another, similar problem.
To call a function from this `mymod` variable, (say your `quit` function), you need to call
`mymod.quit.quit`

The first `quit` is the file name (the one in variable `file`). The second, the function name.

I take you have your own idea about how to deal with functions names (you said nothing about it. Tho I suspect you'll end up with some ugly `eval` and `exec` here, since you probably want to know only at runtime the name of those functions to call­ — it looks like you are trying to write a sort of interpreter with dynamically loaded new functions. Unless all files contain always the same function names. But well, let's focus on the problem you've asked a question about, rather than on the one I predict you'll have afterward).

But you wouldn't have a way to extract `mymod.quit`, the module, since, there again, it expect a literal module name (you can't, like in pandas for example, use alternative syntax `mymod['quit']` instead of `mymod.quit`.

But there is another `__` to help (even if, rule of thumb, the more `__` you use in a code, the worse the solution, imho. That means we are relying a bit too much on functions supposed to be internal), using `__getattribute__` method.

So if the module name is in variable `file`, the you can get the module itself by

```py
mymod = __import__('funcs', file)
fileMod == mymod.__getattribute__(file)
# Which then allows
fileMod.quit()
```

And there, we have a 3rd similar problem: you don't want, probably, to have the module stored in a variable named `fileMod`, but, as `from funcs import quit as quit` would have done, into a variable named `quit`, not `file`.
You could there (that an awful idea, but, imho, the whole thing is an awful idea. It is probably a XY Problem, and I should probably have asked "what do you really want to do", instead  of giving this answer :D) use `globals()` to create a new global variable whose name is the one in variable `file`

So altogether

```py
mymod=__import__('funcs', file)
globals()[file] = mymod.__getattribute__(file)
# Then you can call
quit.quit()
```

Probably a more reasonable solution would be to let all your functions (since, after all, they are all in dir `funcs` in a single package

```py
import os 

commands=[]
for file in os.listdir(r"funcs"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        commands.append(file)
funcs = __import__("funcs", fromlist=commands)
# Then
funcs.quit.quit()
```

And then call `funcs.quit.quit()` rather than `quit.quit()`

Another more reasonable solution would be to use `importlib` package, that bundle some utility function to call `__import__` (but that doesn't solve any of the 3 mentioned problem. Just, it removes some `__`)

But I surmise the only reasonable solution is to understand what are you really trying to do, and try to do it in a way that relies less on `__` :D

Comment: i wanted to make it like the comands in cmd, ill read about importlib